# How to reuse Material UI styles

Tags: material-ui

I have a custom component and would like to apply the exact same styles as the `<Typography>` component gets when setting the `noWrap` prop. The following does work:

```html
<span className="MuiTypography-noWrap">
```

But there's of course no actual type-checking or "link" to anything here, which means if the name ever changes or is removed in a future version, I won't get any type/build error from it.

Is there a "Material UI way" to reuse/copy these classes? E.g. is there somewhere I can import/access these names from?

Comment: Your above example will only work if you have a `Typography` element also present on the page.

Comment: There is documentation specifically around what you're asking here: https://material-ui.com/components/typography/#theme.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a reason, but given your example of a `span` element, I can't help but wonder why you're not just using the MUI component.

I've never done this before, but I was curious and the styles are indeed exported. Not sure if this is a good idea or if there is another way...

```
import { styles } from '@material-ui/core/Typography/Typography';

const noWrapStyles = styles(theme).noWrap;
```